# How to choose the right optimization algorithm for this little problem?

Tags: optimization

Suppose that I have the following dataset:
[image]

My goal is to maximize(WR,ROI) and minimize(DD), based on INPUT_1 and INPUT_2

Which kind of algorithm is adapted for that problem

P.S: memory is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

The question is still not clear for me.

Are Input 1 and 2 can be only 1 or 2? Or any integers? or any real number?

And what do you mean by doing maximize one objective and minimize another objective at same time? Or how to decide if there are conflicts?

If the input 1 and 2 can only be 1 or 2, using the brute force is a solution, which means we just calculate the objective for all possible inputs and pick the best one.

Comment: Input 1 and 2 can be any integers
and I meant by maximizing and minimizing that I want these inputs give the best possible values I can have for WR and ROI, while having the least possible value for DD

..Maybe I should have talked about PAIR section also, that we MIGHT not have the same amount of observations for all the pairs..
thank you